# Varnish Cache Magento 2 SSL offloading - X-Forwarded-Proto: https vs SSL-OFFLOADED: https

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, varnish, magento2.3.5

Previously (older Magento 2.2~ versions), exporting `default.vcl` Varnish Magento 2 configuration:

> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache -> Varnish Configuration : Export VCL for Varnish 4.0

This gave me a comment inside `default.vcl` created:

```
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'
```

Now, with Magento v2.3.5 VCL files for `4,5,6` are :

```
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'
```

What is the difference between the two Headers, do I need to use both or update from `X-Forwarded-Proto` to `SSL-OFFLOADED`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Varnish Cache doesn't have native TLS support, you'll need TLS termination software to handle the TLS part for you. This also means that Varnish only accepts plain HTTP.

However, your Magento server does rely on HTTPS, but Varnish only sends plain HTTP.
To make Magento *TLS-aware*, a specific header can be sent, containing the protocol that was used by the client to connect.

Typically, the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is used for that. It either contains `http` or `https`. Magento uses this value to use the proper URL scheme in the links it builds.

Apparently `SSL-OFFLOADED` is the one your Magento installation prefers.

My advice is to just set both. Just add the following code in your *Nginx* config, just before `proxy_pass`:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded $scheme;
```

> HTTP headers are case-insensitive, to the casing doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks :)

I have a Nginx proxy, with Apache2 that handles Magento2 (PHP).  Varnish should be used in Nginx I guess - proxy_pass https://site:6081.  Is this correct?

Comment: Just added the Nginx config to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, as the other question showed, turns out that SSL_OFFLOADED most likely came from my migrated Magento 1 data.  I always assumed Magento 2.3 exports for new VCL files are **default configurations** (without relying of values defined in database - except for the Access List, Host, Port settings in backend).  I will use both as you suggest.  `$scheme` is the protocol correct? `https/http` for instance?

Comment: @CvRChameleon Absolutely, if you go to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html and look for `$scheme`, you'll see the values it can have. It's either `http` or `https`, based on the URL scheme that was received by Nginx for this request.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually the other way around.

At least based on `app/code/Magento/Store/etc/config.xml`, [only at Magento 2.0](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Store/etc/config.xml#L79) there was a preference towards `SSL_OFFLOADED`. This is more or less "legacy" header name back from Magento 1.x

The `X-Forwarded-Proto` is used, by default, from Magento 2.1 onwards (check [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Store/etc/config.xml#L79)).
It is a de-facto standard (but not official) header name for forwarding the original (often client's) protocol.

Note that which header Magento will use to find out if the connection was over TLS, is stored in the configuration.

If you exported configuration to `app/etc/config.php` it is stored in that file, e.g.:

```
'secure' => [
    'base_web_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}',
    ...
    'offloader_header' => 'SSL_OFFLOADED',
    ...
```

Otherwise, it is stored in `core_config_data`, under the key `web/secure/offloader_header`.

So if you are upgrading from version to version, the value is preserved. E.g. if you installed from Magento 2.0 and were upgrading all the way to Magento 2.3.x, Magento will still use `SSL_OFFLOADED`.

On a new install of Magento >= 2.1.x, the value would default to `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Be noted, that depending on how you configure your stack, you may not need to bother with whether Magento 2 sees any header like this at all.

E.g. with NGINX, you can simply tell that the connection is being handled over HTTPS via `fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https if_not_empty;` where the variable in question is made up by mapping out the actual header you configure:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
    default off;
    https on;
}
```

Then *any* PHP code would correctly identify the connection as encrypted and there would be no reliance on SSL offloading headers in PHP code itself.

Comment: Thanks Danila, I am now really confused to be honest.  I just did new exports again on my `v2.3.5` - and they show `SSL_OFFLOADED`.    The reason why I originally exported new ones was because my new installation complains about my old `v4.0 default.vcl` file. 

Everywhere `return (miss);` used to be will fail when Varnish starts up - and **the new export has `return (restart);` for v6 files.

**ALL `v4,5,6` newly exported entries** use   `SSL-OFFLOADED`  

if (req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED) { hash_data(req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED); }. I am confused because this is the opposite of what you say.

Comment: It is also stored in the database configuration. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the explanation cleared up the confusion : I am migrating data from Magento 1, and never realized that the new exports built parameters based on configuration - from the `database` (in my case `web/secure/offloader_header` in `core_config_data`) or `app/etc/config.php` (didn't exist here).

Comment: How would I be able to create the map as your sample were for `fastcgi_param` when I use Nginx as proxy, Varnish cache, and Apache as web Server?

Comment: `fastcgi_param` applies only when you use NGINX as the web server. Since you already use it as proxy (for TLS I guess), I would ditch Apache completely.

Comment: I will consider this thanks, however Magento 2 has so many `.htaccess` configurations in its folder/subfolders.  Just wonder how much of these I would need to rewrite into Nginx configurations?.  Also the other issue is I use Docker containers (`Nginx-proxy`, `Web-Server`, `Apache2`, `Redis`), so although I can ditch Apache2 container, I would need to make sure I install the relevant PHP modules into Nginx container.